# Login Screen for Windows Store App - What would be the best approach?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I've just started developing for Windows Store App and I have an app which requires a login screen. This login is just to select user records and should not be related to any social network.
My first approach was create a XAML page and load that page when the app starts, in the App.xaml.cs
Then I saw some people using Popups to ask for login, handling the code in the Main.xaml code behind.
What would be the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saving credentials or is the user required to login each time they use the app? Is there a chance that the credentials are changed/expired during using the app? For example Active Directory credentials? What about suspending the app, will the user have to login again when resuming?

Comment: @ChristiaanV Thanks for the comment. No I will not save credentials, it's a business app, the user will be required to login each time he/she uses the app. During the use of app, the user can log out. This app will have two profiles, one administrator and an operator. No, no AD credentials. Yes, coming from suspending the user will have to login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both options are possible. Based on your comments I would suggest build a Login usercontrol that you can use at multiple places. Because you have to login everytime the user starts the app, I would build a loginpage where the app default navigates to from the app.xaml.cs

In case where the app is resumed and you determine that the user has to login again to continue using the app, I would use an overlay over the page where the user already was and load the usercontrol. When the user is logged in again, you can just hide the overlay and the user can continue where he left.

Pro: No logic for remembering where the user came from.

Con: Overlay should be added on every page.

Comment: Yes. I think that confirms my first approach! Buiding a page for the login. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft give some Guidelines for login. [You can get it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965453.aspx).

Guidelines are not an obligation. It is just classic and valid way to do something. Maybe a pop up is an accepted idea, for now maybe you should follow the "basic" way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the guideline confusing, that's why I'm asking here. Reading there I understand that the login should be accessed from a swipe from the edge but this app should have the login  right at the startup, after the splash screen.

Comment: @Ralph You overlooked this: _When your app requires users to log in or create an account when the app first runs, the first screen of the application should feature the login UI prominently._ Your first approach was exactly how they want you to do it.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Yes, I agree. I think that would be the best approach. Thanks for the confirmation!